# A question about the definition of generalized eigenspace

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given an $n\times n$ matrix $A$, its generalized eigenspace pertaining to an eigenvalue $\lambda_i$ is defined as

> $V_{\lambda_i}=\{x:(A-\lambda_i I)^n x=0\}$

The question is to prove

> $V_{\lambda_i}=\{x:(A-\lambda_i I)^n x=0\} = \{x:(A-\lambda_i I)^{m(\lambda_i)} x=0\}$ where $m(\lambda_i)$ is the algebraic multiplicity of $\lambda_i$.

It is obvious that $\{x:(A-\lambda_i I)^{m(\lambda_i)} x=0\} \subseteq \{x:(A-\lambda_i I)^n x=0\}$, since $(A-\lambda_i I)^{m(\lambda_i)} x=0\Rightarrow (A-\lambda_i I)^n x=0$. The problem is the other direction.

The solution hints that using Hamilton-Cayley theorem, i.e.

> $\prod\limits_{{\lambda } \in \sigma (A)} {{{(A - {\lambda}I)}^{m({\lambda })}}}  = O$ where ${\sigma (A)}$ is the spectrum of $A$
>
> [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since we are proving the blue-lined statement, we write 
$$V_{\lambda_i}=\{x: (A-\lambda_i)^{m(\lambda_i)}x=0\}.$$
We prove that $\mathbb{C}^n=\oplus_{i=1}^j V_{\lambda_i}$.

Let $v_1\in V_{\lambda_1}, v_2\in V_{\lambda_2}, \ldots, v_j\in V_{\lambda_j}$.  Suppose that there is a linear relation between these   vectors:
$$
\sum_{i=1}^j   v_i=0.
$$
For each $i$, let  $f_i(t)=\frac{p_A(t)}{(t-\lambda_i)^{m(\lambda_i)}}$. We obtain by Cayley-Hamilton theorem that 
$$
   f_i(A) v_i = 0.
$$ 
We define
$$
f(t) := \sum_{i=1}^j \frac{f_i(t)}{f_i(\lambda_i)} -1.
$$
This polynomial satisfies $f(\lambda_i)=0$ for each $i$. Then $f(t) = g(t)\prod_i (t-\lambda_i)$ for some polynomial $g(t)$. This gives
$$
f(A) = g(A)\prod_i (A-\lambda_i)=\sum_{i=1}^j \frac{f_i(A)}{f_i(\lambda_i)} -I \ \ \ (*).
$$
Applying this to $v_i$, we have 
$$
v_i = \frac{f_i(A)v_i }{f_i(\lambda_i)}-g(A)\prod_i (A-\lambda_i)v_i=-g(A)\prod_i (A-\lambda_i)v_i
$$
A finitely many iteration of above, gives $v_i=0$.

Again by applying $(*)$ to $v$, we have for any $v\in \mathbb{C}^n$, 
$$v = \sum_{i=1}^j \frac{f_i(A)v }{f_i(\lambda_i)}-g(A)\prod_i (A-\lambda_i)v.$$

With a finitely many iteration of above, we obtain that $v\in \sum_{i=1}^j V_{\lambda_i}$. Since the sum is direct by the first part, we have $v\in \oplus_{i=1}^j V_{\lambda_i}$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How do you obtain form Hamilton-Cayley theorem that $f_i(\lambda_i) v_i = 0$?

Comment: If $j\neq i$, then $f_i(A) v_j = 0$, and $f_i(A) v_i = f_i(\lambda_i) v_i$.

Comment: Thanks. I understand $f_i(A) v_j = 0$ but why $f_i(A) v_i = f_i(\lambda_i) v_i$? $v_i$ is a generalized eigenvector, not eigenvector, can we still replace the polynomial $f_i(A)$ by $f_i(\lambda_i)$?

Comment: It seems that I made a mistake using that $v_i$ is eigenvectors. Sorry for this, I will correct this soon.

Comment: Now, fixed this.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I still don't get why $f_i(A) v_i = 0$. $f_i(A)$ is the polynomial with factor $(t-\lambda_i)^{m(\lambda_i)}$ removed, how do we have $f_i(A) v_i = 0$ from Hamilton-Cayley theorem?

Comment: I got it. It is because you let $\sum_{i=1}^j   v_i=0$.

Comment: Could you help explain a bit more about "a finitely many iteration of above, gives $v_i=0$" and how "a finitely many iteration of above, we obtain that $v\in \oplus_{i=1}^j V_{\lambda_i}$"? Many thanks!

Comment: A finitely many iteration means that applying the formula for $v$ repeatedly. Then it accumulates powers of $(A-\lambda_i)$ leading to $(A-\lambda_i)^{m(\lambda_i)}$ in finite steps.

Comment: Thanks again! Got the point for $v_i$! but about $v = \sum_{i=1}^j \frac{f_i(A)v }{f_i(\lambda_i)}-g(A)\prod_i (A-\lambda_i)v$, how do we go from this to $v\in \oplus_{i=1}^j V_{\lambda_i}$?

Comment: The first part shows that the sum decomposition must be direct. The second part shows that the sum decomposition exists.

Comment: Yes. I understand the first part is to prove $V_{\lambda_i}$s are linearly independent so the direct sum is valid. But the second part, I am puzzling over why $v = \sum_{i=1}^j \frac{f_i(A)v }{f_i(\lambda_i)}-g(A)\prod_i (A-\lambda_i)v$ implies every $v$ of $\Bbb C$ is actually inside the space of the direct sum?

Comment: It will suffice to prove that $v$ is in the sum (because directness was proven in the first part). Repeatedly applying the formula for $v$ finitely many times, we will obtain $v=\sum_i c_i f_i(A) w_i$ for some constants $c_i$ and vectors $w_i$. Then each $f_i(A)w_i$ belongs to $V_{\lambda_i}$ by Cayley-Hamilton.

Comment: Thanks again. If we plug $v$ into itself, say $n$ times, since ${(\sum\limits_{i = 1}^j {\frac{{{f_i}(A)}}{{{f_i}({\lambda _i})}}} )^k} = \sum\limits_{i = 1}^j {\frac{{{f_i}^k(A)}}{{{f_i}^k({\lambda _i})}}} $,

Comment: Then $v = {(\sum\limits_{i = 1}^j {\frac{{{f_i}(A)}}{{{f_i}({\lambda _i})}}}  - g(A)\prod\limits_{i = 1}^j {(A - {\lambda _i}I)} )^n}v = (\sum\limits_{k = 0}^n {(\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
  n \\ 
  k 
\end{array}} \right)} \sum\limits_{i = 1}^j {\frac{{{f_i}^k(A)}}{{{f_i}^k({\lambda _i})}}} {g^{n - k}}(A)\prod\limits_{i = 1}^j {{{(A - {\lambda _i}I)}^{n - k}})} )v$.It seems very complicated. Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: So, $f_i(A)w \in V_{\lambda_i}$ for any vector $w$. You don't need to iterate in full detail. Just observe that each iteration gives a sum of $f_i(A)w$ for some $w$ and $\prod_{i=1}^j(A-\lambda_iI) w$. So, each iteration adds up the powers of each $A-\lambda_iI$. Do this until you obtain the power of $m(\lambda_i)$ for some $i$.

Comment: This is a great proof! I am really curious how this special function $f(t)$ is found :)

Answer (score 3):

To simplify notation, take $\lambda$ to be $\lambda_r$, the last one. Write $m_j$ instead of $m(\lambda_j)$.

Suppose that there exists $x$ with $(A-\lambda_r I)^{m_r}x\ne0$ and $$\tag{*}(A-\lambda_r I)^{m_r+1}x=0.$$ We have
$$\tag{**}
\prod_{j=1}^{r-1}(A-\lambda_j I)^{m_j}\,(A-\lambda_r I)^{m_r}x=0.
$$
Write $$v=(A-\lambda_1 I)^{m_1-1}\prod_{j=2}^{r-1}(A-\lambda_j I)^{m_j}\,(A-\lambda_r I)^{m_r}x.$$
Then by $(**)$ we have $(A-\lambda_1 I)v=0$. We also have, using that all terms commute, that $(A-\lambda_r I)v=0$. Thus $\lambda_1 v=\lambda_r v$, which implies that $v=0$. In other words, we were able to reduce the power in $(**)$ by $1$.

If we keep repeating this procedure many times, we'll eventually get to
$$
(A-\lambda_{r-1}I)\,(A-\lambda_r I)^{m_r}x=0.
$$
Applying the above reasoning one again, we get that $(A-\lambda_r I)^{m_r}x=0$, a contradiction.

It follows that $$V_{\lambda}=\{x:(A-\lambda I)^n x=0\} = \{x:(A-\lambda I)^{m(\lambda)} x=0\}.$$ The procedure can be repeated for any $\lambda$.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach (the one taken in Axler's book). It avoids the Cayley-Hamilton theorem, using only the ideas of "subspace", "dimension", and "kernel" and the elementary results surrounding them.

Let $A$ be an $n \times n$ matrix. We have the following facts about powers of $A$ (try proving them and see if you like this method better):

1. $\{0\} = \ker A^0 \subseteq \ker A^1 \subseteq \ker A^2 \subseteq \cdots$.
2. If $j$ is an integer such that $\ker A^j = \ker A^{j+1}$, then the inclusions in 1 "terminate" (become equalities): $$ \{0\} \subseteq \ker A^1 \subseteq \cdots \subseteq \ker A^j = \ker A^{j+1} = \ker A^{j+2} = \cdots. $$
3. $\ker A^n = \ker A^{n+1}$, i.e., the inclusions must terminate before the $(n+1)$st power: $$ \{0\} \subseteq \ker A^1 \subseteq \cdots \subseteq \ker A^n = \ker A^{n+1} = \cdots. $$

Now if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, consider the above inclusions with $A$ replaced by $A - \lambda I$. Let $j$ be the least integer for which the inclusions terminate, so the inclusions before the power $j$ are *strict*. We get
$$
(*) \quad \{0\} \subsetneq \ker(A - \lambda I)^1 \subsetneq \cdots \subsetneq \ker(A - \lambda I)^j = \cdots = \ker(A - \lambda I)^n.
$$
We know that $j$ exists because fact 3 says $j \leq n$.

Now, the algebraic multiplicity $m$ of $\lambda$ is defined to be $m = \dim \ker (A - \lambda I)^n$. Since the $\subsetneq$'s in $(*)$ are *strict* inlcusions of *subspaces*, the dimension must increase by at least $1$ each time (this is how we prove fact 3 above!); hence $\dim \ker (A - \lambda I)^j \geq j$. Thus by taking dimensions in $(*)$ we have 
$$
j \leq \dim \ker (A - \lambda I)^j = \cdots = \dim \ker (A - \lambda I)^n = m.
$$
Using $j \leq m$  and $(*)$ once more, we see that 
$$
\ker (A - \lambda I)^j = \cdots = \ker (A - \lambda I)^m = \cdots = \ker (A - \lambda I)^n,
$$
and the last equality is what you wanted.

Comment: Does this approach show that $m(\lambda)$ is the algebraic multiplicity of $\lambda$?

Comment: No, in fact it's not, so maybe my post is a bit misleading. I'll fix it now.

Comment: Fixed! (Now $m$ corresponds to algebraic multiplicity as in OP.)

Comment: I kind of feel you are cheating a little. The algebraic multiplicity is the multiplicity as a root of the characteristic polynomial. Showing that it agrees with $\dim\ker(A-\lambda I)^n$ is the whole point of the question.

Comment: It's not cheating! It's an equivalent definition to the one you gave. I like it because, for me, it's more intuitive. Also, showing that $m = \dim \ker(A - \lambda I)^n$ is not the point of the question; it's to show that $\ker (A - \lambda I)^m \supseteq \ker(A - \lambda I)^n$ (since the reverse inclusion is obvious). And showing $\ker (A - \lambda I)^m \supseteq \ker(A - \lambda I)^n$ is what I did.

Comment: It's equivalent, of course, but that's the point of the question. You cannot really expect to define the **algebraic** multiplicity with a **geometric** definition.

Comment: One *can* define the algebraic multiplicity with a geometric definition. Algebraically, the multiplicity $m$ of $\lambda$ is the power of the term $(t - \lambda)$ in the factored characteristic polynomial $\det(tI - A)$. Geometrically, $m = \dim \ker (A - \lambda I)^n$. Since you agree that these definitions are equivalent, you must concede that algebraic multiplicity can be defined geometrically. Again, the equivalence of the definitions is intimately related to, but not the point of, the OP. See sec 3, 5, 9 of http://www.axler.net/DwD.pdf